# How to pass/reference form class parameters to/from other procedures

Tags: vb.net, forms, class, parameter-passing

I have 2 forms: street and address
I want to define a variable in each of them which has the same name so that when i call either form from a procedure I can use that variable regardless of which form it is I am calling.

For example, Street form would look like this

```
Public Class Street

  Public ID As Integer = 0

  Private Sub LoadForm()
    Dim myID As integer = ID
  End Sub

End Class
```

And Address form would look like this:

```
Public Class Address

  Public ID As Integer = 0

  Private Sub LoadForm()
    Dim myID As integer = ID
  End Sub

End Class
```

My ParentMDI menus would be:

```
Private Sub AddressClick()
  Call Address(Address)
End Sub

Private Sub StreetClick()
  Call Address(Street)
End Sub
```

and a module that has the procedure opening the forms would look like this:

```
Module Caller

  Public Sub Address(ByVal frm As Form)
    '...several codes here
    If IamHappy Then
      frm.ID = 2'this is illegal because ID is not part of form parameters
    Else
      frm.ID = 3'this is illegal because ID is not part of form parameters
    End if
    frm.show()
  End Sub

End Module
```

Basically, I dont want the menus to do 'hard work' because the forms can be called from several different menus/sources. I want the public procedure in the module to be the one tasked with assigning values form my forms parameters before opening it.

I have seen discussions of how to send a class as a parameter, but that does not help me to get the declared value 'ID' in the form class. I am thinking there could be a way to create my own variables to become part of my forms? Or whichever method is suitable to achieve this.

**Edit to provide some more info**

1. A separate login procedure will set for me a public UserID
2. MDI menu is suppose to tell me which form the user wants to open after login
3. Caller module is suppose to combine the information of which form is
   requested and the ID of the user.
4. a) Set the state of the form before opening it, eg, if form tag = 2 then do not open it for this user (I am OK up to here), b) set the form's states using the Caller module then go ahead and open it. This is where the problem is. I want to set printID, for example, to 1 = user can print; or 2, user should not print.

I want to manage 4. b) in the publicly declared module instead of the menu or inside the particular form because i have many forms in this application.

Unless there is a better way to this than how i am approaching it...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Windows.Forms.Form` does not have an ID property.  When you call the Address Sub, you are casting your `Address` and `Street` Forms back to a simple form.  You could write a baseclass form with ID in it, and have Address and Street inherit from it, then:

```
  Public Sub Address(ByVal frm As MDIChildBase)
```

Or you can use an overload:

```
  Public Sub Address(ByVal frm As Address)

  Public Sub Address(ByVal frm As Street)
```

This will result in a bit more code and seems to be what you are trying to avoid.

OR cast the `frm` variable back to the type if you can tell which one you want:

```
  Public Sub Address(ByVal frm As Form)
    '...several codes here
    If ICanTellWhichIsWhich Then
      CType(frm, Address).ID = 2
```

None of these are ideal.  *Generally* it is better to have a class managing all this which would have an actual reference to the forms involved and know what to do and how to do it.  The less program logic in forms, the better.

---

However, you also appear to be using the default instance for the forms:

```
Private Sub AddressClick()
  Call Address(Address)
End Sub
```

Forms are classes and as such should be instanced explicitly:

```
Dim frmA As New Address
...
frmA.Show 
...
Call Address(frmA)
```

Comment: Thanks. I picked up a few ideas from your post which I am currently trying out. Particularly, creating baseclass form. I don't know how to implement overload. But the third suggestions, rightly put, is what I am trying to avoid - I can have very many forms!

Comment: The problem with a form baseclass is that it needs to be compiled for the IDE to pick up the properties. if a *class* had a reference to the form(s) `frmAddr As Address` you can reference everything like you want with no special steps

Comment: I have hit a brick wall with the things I am trying. So how do I implement this with a class - I can't make the connection because I only know how to create classes independent of forms. Let me explain more elaborately exactly what I am trying to do so you can help. the ID is used to check if the user has permission to print the data. If ID = 1, the print button in the form will be disabled. So i need an external way to set the value of this ID in each form before it opens. I am now using tag, but this is limited to only one variable at a time, thus unflexible.